# FreeRTOS cannot poll input pins when using vTaskDelayUntil()

Tags: polling, freertos, rtos

I'm facing weird behavior with FreeRTOS code.
Especially when using `vTaskDelayUntil()` and `vTaskDelay()`

I'm trying to read an input pin from my PIR sensor.
On the scope I see that the PIR is holding 3.3v high for at least 1 second.

The code below only reads my PIR input when I comment out the ' vTaskDelayUntil' line. As soon as I activate that line, PINC register is always 0.
Also when I'm sure there is 3.3v on my input pin.

```
static void TaskStatemachine(void *pvParameters) 
{
    (void) pvParameters;
    TickType_t xLastWakeTime;
    const TickType_t xFrequency = 100; 

    xLastWakeTime = xTaskGetTickCount();

    for(;;)
    {
        printf("PINC.1 = %d\n", (PINC & (1<<1) ));
        vTaskDelayUntil( &xLastWakeTime, ( xFrequency / portTICK_PERIOD_MS ) );
    }
}
```

What is happening here?
I changed xFrequency to different values, but without any luck.

Comment: Did you see the log? 
Seems problem in PINC, not in FreeRTOS. How to declared PINC? did you use volatile keyword?

Comment: PINC is a define pointing to the right register value. This is device specific and coming from avr/io.h

Comment: When removing the vTaskDelayUntil the value is updated and you can see the value of the printf changing ? With vTaskDelayUntil/vTaskDelay are the prints at the correct frequency? Can you show the declaration of PINC ?

Comment: How much stack have you given the task? Formatted I/O functions such as `printf()` are expensive in stack terms.  If you have a stack overflow, you will observe a range of non-deterministic behaviour.  Including possibly this.

Comment: Rather than declaring `xFrequency`, and calculating the loop invariant delay on every iteration, suggest `const TickType_t delay_ticks = 100 /  portTICK_PERIOD_MS ;`

Comment: @Clifford you are right, I am going to delete my comment because it is wrong and worthless. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As an experiment, simplify the output thus:

```
putchar( (PINC & (1<<1)) == 0 ? '0' : '1' ) ;
```

You will then get a continuous stream of 1 or 0.

If that works with or without the delay, then it seems likely that that the task has too small a stack to support `printf()`.  Try increasing the stack and putting the `printf()` back in.

Comment: I think you are on the right track here. How do I decide how big the stack size has to be for every task. If I increase them randomly, some tasks stop running or my whole program hangs.

Comment: @user3411864 : That is a different question - best post a separate question to get a wider audience, but there are already answers to similar questions on SO.  It is hard to see how "too much" stack will cause a problem if you have the space.  It seems more likely that you are using FreeRTOS's automatic stack allocation which allocates the stack from the heap, and you are running out of heap space.  Better to use `xTaskCreateStatic` perhaps, then any memory exhaustion will be detected at build time rather than run-time, which is easier to debug.

Comment: I have seen `printf()` implementations use as much as 4kb.   When you ask the question, include information about the tool-chain you are using and the target device.